# AWS Transcribe REST API

Tags: python, node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, transcription

AWS recently released a very exciting [transcribe library](https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/).

It seems that the API for using it is only using [python (boto) or their CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/getting-started-asc-api.html)

I'd like to use NodeJS API or at least to have REST API.

I was not able to find REST API, does anyone know something about it?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Documentation for Transcribe API is available here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/what-is-transcribe.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).